# XFCE Login Error: Unable to Load Failsafe Session

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, xfce4, xdg

I'm having a problem logging into xfce under Arch Linux.

---

**Problem:**
After logging in (with Slim like I usually do), I get this error message:

```
Unable to load a failsafe session
Unable to determine failsafe session name. Possible causes xconfd isn't running (D-Bus setup problem);
environment variable $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set incorrectly (must include "/etc") or xfce4-session is installed incorrectly.
```

---

**Fixes that did NOT work:**
I found these fixes on Google, but none of them worked for me.
1. Make sure `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is set correctly:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
```

2. Make sure everything in my home directory has correct permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME
```

3. Change permissions of `/etc/xdg`:
*(I later realized that this must be an old fix because Arch recommends **755** permissions for `/etc/xdg`, NOT 644)*

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/xdg
```

4. Try to start an xfce session manually:
*(because this did not work, I know that the problem is with **xfce** and not SLIM)*

```
startxfce4
```

5. Total reinstall of all xfce apps:

```
yaourt -Sa $(yaourt -Qsq xfce)
```

6. Remove xfce config and then reinstall everything (in order to make sure that xfce settings are reset to default)

```
mv ~/.config/xfce ~/.config/xfce.bak
yaourt -Sa $(yaourt -Qsq xfce)
```

7. Deleting session cache:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/sessions/
```

---

I'd list the output of `yaourt -Qsq xfce` if I could, but I'd need to login to my computer in order to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with `xfce4-session-devel`. The latest update doesn't work on my system. Installing the stable `xfce4-session` package would have been the correct fix:

```
sudo pacman -S xfce4-session
```

Answer (score 7):

The way work for me is to replace `exec startxfce 4` by `dbus-launch xfce4-session`

The `xstartup` file looks like the following:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 unset SESSION_MANAGER
 unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
 dbus-launch xfce4-session
```

Comment: Only this variant worked for me on Debian 10, thank you bro!

Comment: Please can you update this answer to latest 21 release

Answer (score 1):

Don't use slim. It's outdated and doesn't support logind and other systemd stuff on arch. Use lightdm with the gtk greeter instead (official Xfce-IRC-help-channel recommendation).

Also`xfce4-session-devel`is outdated in favor for`xfce4-session`since the 4.12 release. I will update`xfce4-session-devel`as soon as a >4.12 development version is released.